# typedef confusion in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm having a hard time understanding the typedefs in this C structure.

```
typedef struct node {
   int   value;
   list  rest;
} node;

typedef struct node *list;
```

What's the difference between the "node" typedef declaration and the "list" declaration? Why is list prefaced as a pointer? Isn't "node" a pointer as well? Why can't I simply say "typedef struct node list" and omit the asterisk? I've been searching everywhere and I can't really find a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 5):

The first `typedef` defines `node` as an alias for `struct node`, to allow you to refer to it simply as `node` without writing `struct node` every time (in C "regular" type names and `struct` names live in two different namespaces). It's equivalent to:

```
struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node* rest;
};

typedef struct node     node;
```

The second `typedef`, instead, defines `list` as an alias for `node *`, i.e. defines the type `list` as *a pointer* to a `node` structure.

(by the way, personally I find that this is very bad style: hiding pointers inside `typedef`s is almost always a bad idea; one can argue that a pointer to the first element in a list could be identified as the list, but the usage of `list` even for the `rest` pointer is IMHO not very nice)

Comment: I personally don't agree with the latter part. The data structure being implemented here is a singly-linked list. Typing it as "just" a node pointer obscures the actual intent.

Comment: Well I do agree with the latter part as I've actually had to work with such nonsense `typedef`'s.

Comment: @Chuck: as I said, I can understand that usage, but I would be using it just to point to the head of the list, not for every "next" pointer. Or, even better, I'd define a separate `struct list { struct node * head; }` to keep the `list` type well distinct from being "just" a `struct node *`

Comment: If you put the typedef above the struct, you can use simply `node* rest`

Comment: @Dave: and I could even unify the struct declaration and the typedef, but I did none of these "compactifications", because the very reason for that code was to explain how it works removing any cross dependence.

Answer (score 1):

`node` is not a pointer; it is a `struct`.  `list` is a typedef for a pointer to `node`.

You `typedef` a `struct` in C to avoid typing `struct node ...` everywhere.

Whether or not this is good practice is questionable (most will agree that hiding a pointer type behind a `typedef`, unless it is truly opaque, is a bad idea), but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 1):

The first declaration says that a `node` is the structure.  The second says that a `list` is a pointer to a node.

So, this would be proper code using those declarations:

```
list  x;
node  n;

x = &n;
```

Declaring an item using `typedef struct node list` is not correct.  The `typedef` statement declares a new type.  The keyword `typedef` is not part of the type's name.

Answer (score 1):

`node` is a `struct`, which is (confusingly) named the same thing as `struct node`. `list` is a pointer to `struct node`. So the following are equivalent:

```
struct node *a;
node *a;
list a;
```

Answer (score 0):

`node` is just a *synonym* for `struct node`

`list` is a *pointer* to a `struct node` (or `node`)

Each node instance contains a `list` pointer which enables you to build data structures such as (singly) [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), etc.